# Wordpress loading posts with AJAX - java loaded but not triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, pjax

The website is here - http://sebastiangraz.com/

As one can see the portfolio items are being loaded with DJAX (http://beezee.github.io/djax.html) with 
the following code:

```
    $('body').djax('.djaxable', ['wp-admin', 'wp-login', '?s=']);
```

All works fine until I click one portfolio item whatever javascript I have on the page doesn't get triggered, but the javascript file gets loaded. For instance if you hard refresh one of the single pages (http://sebastiangraz.com/portfolio/konsthallen) you can hover the big title at the top and it will change to "< return " however if you access the same page via the frontpage the javascript for the hover effect doesn't work anymore.

I wish someone could take a quick look at whats going on here. That would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: scripts in content passed to `$()` get executed immediately, which is before the `.append` happens to add them to the DOM. because of this, you won't be able to solve this without modifying the djax plugin or rolling your own. https://github.com/beezee/djax/blob/master/jquery.djax.js#L122 You could also do some kind of setTimeout/setInterval loop that waits till the elements it's looking for exist.

Comment: I'm ready to do that if that's what it takes. Do you have any pointers?

Comment: which *"that"* are you referring to? roll your own? or the loop. The loop would be relatively easy to implement, i'd just need to see the code that is being pulled in via ajax.

Comment: the interval loop would look similar to this: http://pastebin.com/X4LTG15r